# Force Flask app to wait until function is finished

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am using Facebook webhook to read messages from our pages inbox and forward them to our helpdesk. To handle this properly it is important that there is a small delay before forwarding the next message. Unfortunately I am not able to handle that correctly.

After receiving the post request the ***do_some_stuff*** function should run, wait a few seconds and process the next one, but the app does not wait and starts the next run even if the previous is not finished. ***sleep*** is completely ignored here.

Guess I am missing something here?

```
@app.route("/callback", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_message():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        token_sent = request.args.get("hub.verify_token")
        return verify_fb_token(token_sent)

    else:
        do_some_stuff()
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I would recommend creating a function decorator that does the await and decorating `do_some_stuff()`. The real or "architectural" question is why do you need to wait between requests at all?

Comment: The messages will be forwarded to our helpdesk provider Helpscout. If we receive a message from a new customer a new Helpscout customer will be created and a conversation started. However, if someone sends 2 or 3 within a few seconds I cannot grab the new created user from Helpscout API and another conversation will be created instead updating the previous one.

Comment: Just as a side-note, time-based event synchronization is usually a mistake and will shoot you in the foot when and where you least expect and it'd be disastrous. One of the better approaches is to query an API in a loop every few seconds to see if your expected user was created.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Fian! But how can I handle this? The problem I face is, if the same user sends a second message directly afterwards this new requests will be handled before the check of the first request is finished. So I basically would just need 1 or 2 secs to hold this second request to make sure the first one is done. I am bit lost here. Sorry.

Comment: Usually such cases are resolved with idempotency. You should choose an idempotency key for your `receive_message` operation, so even multiple requests are sent (with the same idempotency key), each idempotency key would be processed only once. From your explanation, I might guess it may be a user id or a message id.

Comment: Thanks @Fian - I will look into this. Currently I solved it by adding the user id of a new message to a list and remove it from the list after the message was fully processed. I can then check new messages if there is a task from the same user  active and use a while loop to wait until it's done.